# How can I tell what my PHP $_Get max value is

Tags: php, magento

I've installed a Magento payment gateway extension, and one of the caveats of the extension is "Some php / server configurations disallow access to the $_GET variable when it contains very long strings (2000+ characters) - if your server does this the extension will not work".

I think this is my case, because the extension is not working, and the log shows a result cut off at 549 characters. The error is similar to someone else who was able to resolve it with php.ini using `suhosin.get.max_value_length = 4000`.

I tried that and `php_value get.max_value_length 4096` in my .htaccess, but it did not fix it. I'm on shared hosting. My phpinfo does not show suhosin, and doesn't have any info related to the $_Get variable.

Short of contacting my host, which I may do, how can I tell if my $_Get variable doesn't allow >549 characters? Can I increase it myself, or do I need my webhost to do this?

```
2013-06-25T02:10:09+00:00 DEBUG (7): MageBaseDps successAction result v5vQIupexyLD3UxBouvx2DLStUSsBqXshGHhPczf-iD7ZVGZvQP8nHhPeSizAJ5j0LqVHgqe2c9h24swuCbGALUGWk041aZM82uCFpLUzLZmKAo5qKAQ4EoYGAwao-GwG96Lk3bK2dU9dqufK9MA6LPVkO62nWVFnJj4i83mQDTts5-r4dq1n3bhqVCE0tR8fW6vgMxVaSe2vI1lqa-3IaHb_iRFBrpSFS91tMX4gOmumJg2OwLGNqyywdmkiH1ywmYDkr46yYjLEsv5h5jTJtF8jtXXJQGOPQ6RE4bxZladjrVtYZRoDOlTy6rK09ktXYKnU8vX8frLOArU8XsCULOFZ-0YYjk0j8Yl-LoWzhlT7ooqDoAzLxtD0R2n53_avOafOqUYFst6vJMPop5fhrZxt2h9ycF50Ir9lZK4MIHsIXCszojrdAWZiDrtOaKzlIUwvO0u2qbr2rkVyA6heTug_ONiyxw7SweEUYKpb8x2059XaG1bqbB6s39e_9cJ_bNUJwd6p1MGtehXuX0wJANWd2Qi2qO-dM
2013-06-25T02:10:09+00:00 DEBUG (7): 301039 MageBaseDps User returned to Success Url
```

Comment: Why would you ever need that long of a get query? Anything longer than 50 characters should be in POST.

Comment: "Short of contacting my host" well that should be your first port of cvall for server configuration

Comment: @Kolink, i have seen it required for some paymentgateways

Comment: @Dagon Well that's just shitty design XD Longest query string I ever needed was `?threadid=12345&postid=1234567`, and that was before I learned about pretty URLs.

Comment: well tell several of the external gateways  i use that :-=)

Comment: My question related to whether this WAS something I could do myself, e.g., per .htaccess, without having to ask the host to do something I could do myself. Per Rob's answer, it turns out I cannot: I now know that this is controlled by Apache's LimitRequestLine Directive, and the context does not allow for .htaccess. :( I will contact my host! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GET max length is not PHP-controlled, it's controlled by the web server (like Apache).

[See this for more info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestline)

Comment: And different browsers have their own limits

Comment: ^ This +1; another reason you shouldn't change the limits.

Comment: there may not be a browser in the loop. such as return hits from payment gateways